# What is the minimum age for a Microsoft store developer (individual)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, store, windows-store

What is the minimum age for the microsoft store developer account. (I'm talking about the individual account, and I also mean the account where you can upload games and software to the store).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a reply from Microsoft Support.

#### Anyone can make an account, if its a minor. The adult needs to help with legal things, like the payment and agreements. [Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453384/what-is-the-minimum-age-for-a-microsoft-store-deve.html)

Answer (score -1):

The minimum age for a Microsoft store developer must be at least 21+ and in 12th stream must be in science with math

Comment: but there are students younger than 21

Comment: Is there an official reference for it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453384/what-is-the-minimum-age-for-a-microsoft-store-deve.html